# CQ5.5: Accessing a referring resource in a osgi servlet

Tags: osgi, aem, sling

I'm curious if there is a way to access a referrer resource from inside an OSGI Servlet.

Example:

1. I have a form component
2. Form component submits to /bin/form (a servlet)
3. Inside the servlet at /bin/form I would like to access the form component Resource - not sure how to do this part

any ideas/thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

thank you,
Brodie

Comment: Are you looking for this http://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling5/org/apache/sling/api/SlingHttpServletRequest.html#getResource() You can access the resource from SlingHttpServletRequest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may add a hidden value with the component resource path:

```
<input type="hidden" name="resourcePath" value="${resource.path}"/>
```

value will be available as `resourcePath` parameter in the servlet code:

```
String resourcePath = request.getParameter("resourcePath");
```

You should check if the resource path is a valid value, as a malicious user can set anything they want there.

Also, please consider the second approach: instead of binding the servlet to a static path `/bin/form` you may bind it to *your component resourceType*. Let's assume that this resource type is `myapp/component/form`. In this case you may declare servlet as follows:

```
@SlingServlet(resourceTypes="myapp/component/form", methods="POST", selectors="form")
public FormServlet extends SlingAllMethodsServlet {
    public doPost(SlingHttpServletRequest request, SlingHttpServletResponse response) {
        Resource formResource = request.getResource();
        // ...
    }
}
```

Form code should look like this:

```
<form action="${resource.path}.form.html" method="post">
    <!-- your form contents here -->
</form>
```

Advantages of this approach:

- you can get the form resource as simply as `request.getResource()`,
- you don't need to perform additional resource path parameter validation,
- it is more *RESTful*.

Comment: Big +1 to the second approach using the resource type to bind the servlet - that's the natural, recommended way in Apache Sling, which powers CQ.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to accept, this is awesome. I didn't think about binding the post handler to the form component itself. This makes it much easier to handle.